# Can I make a Modal without Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have been tasked with creating a modal, but I was told that the Bootstrap library will not be available to me in this build. Is it possible to build a modal without Bootstrap classes? If so, can someone guide me to some documentation?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </h4>
            </div><!-- modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Select the options below to get the right coverage type for you.</p>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!-- modal-body -->
        </div><!-- modal-content -->
    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->
```

My next step was to put in there:

```
<div class="form-group"></div>
```

but that is a Bootstrap class, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is it possible to build a modal without Bootstrap classes?

A [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) is an overlay that prevents the user to interact with some parent content. It is not proprietary of [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), although Bootstrap [makes it very easy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) to implement one by adding css classes. Underneath, Bootstrap uses [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) to implement most of its functionality, including the modals.

You can implement it by using any other library [for example Bulma](https://bulma.io) , by using another framework that uses jquery, [for example jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/dialog), by using any other javascript library that could implement a modal, or by implementing it using javascript, or even with only css and html.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) is a simple tutorial on how to create a modal using javascript and css.

[This](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) is a tutorial on how to create a modal without javascript, only html5 and css.

These tutorials are very useful if you don't want your code to be dependant of any third-party library, like jquery.

If you don't want to (or can't) use bootstrap, but you can use jquery, you can follow [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/) tutorial.

Comment: It should be noted that neither of the roll-your-own tutorials above are feature complete. They're missing critical things esc to close, capturing focus, key accessibility features (role, aria attributes), and disabling document scroll. A more robust example (although still not perfect) can be found here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/dialog-modal/dialog

Comment: It's unfortunate that building a reasonable dialog is a fairly involved process. If you can use a library, that's often the best bet. But keep an eye on the HTML Dialog Element - browser support is improving. Otherwise, be prepared to spent a good chunk of time getting it right

Answer (score 3):

There's this Jquery plugin, take a look: https://jqueryui.com/dialog

Answer (score 0):

**Html part**

```
 <div class="demo-description">
   This page demonstrates a modal dialog without any third-party libraries. It uses only CSS + plain (vanilla) javascript.

   <ul>
      <li><a class="modal-toggle" data-target="openModal1">Open Modal window 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="modal-toggle" data-target="openModal2">Open Modal window 2</a></li>

      <li><button class="modal-toggle" data-target="openModal1">Open Modal window 1</button></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="openModal1" class="modal-wrapper">
   <div class="modal">
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h2>Modal Box 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-content">
         <p>Some text for selection</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="openModal2" class="modal-wrapper">
   <div class="modal">
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-content">
         <p>Some text for selection</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS PART**

```
    body {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   padding: 30px;
}
.demo-description {
   max-width: 460px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   line-height: 1.5;
}

.modal-toggle {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #268bd2;
}
.modal-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;

   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 0;

   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
   transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;

   pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal-wrapper > div {
   width: 460px;
   height: 40%;
   position: absolute;

   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;

   margin: auto;

   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 20px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   background: #fff;
   z-index: 1;
}

.close {
   background: #606061;
   color: #ffffff;
   line-height: 25px;
   position: absolute;
   right: -12px;
   text-align: center;
   top: -10px;
   width: 24px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
   -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
   -moz-border-radius: 12px;
   border-radius: 12px;
}

.close:hover {
   background: #00d9ff;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var cb = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
   cb[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var dia = this.parentNode.parentNode; /* You need to update this part if you change level of close button */
      dia.style.opacity = 0;
      dia.style.zIndex = -1;
   });
}

var mt = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-toggle");
for (i = 0; i < mt.length; i++) {
   mt[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var targetId = this.getAttribute("data-target");
      var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
      target.style.opacity = 1;
      target.style.zIndex = 9999;
   });
}
```

Comment: While their content may be valid, code-only answers get poor reception on SO. Please see [answer] for good tips, then please elaborate on how you complement  this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289222/12846804